# Generate view description based on parent docstring

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

How can I generate a class-based view description for my API based on Django-REST-Framework from the parent view (useful for nested ressources) ?

I have a parent class like :

```
class ParentView(GenericAPIView):
    """
    My parent endpoint documentation
    """
    pass
```

and a child class like:

```
class ChildView(ParentView):
    """
    My child endpoint documentation
    """
    pass
```

When browsing the interactive API for the child view, the generated description is "My child endpoint documentation" but I want to have "My parent endpoint documentation" instead.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to overload the `get_view_description` method in child view like :

```
class ChildView(ParentView):
    def get_view_description(self, html=False):
        """
        Get the view description based on the parent class docstring
        """
        func = self.settings.VIEW_DESCRIPTION_FUNCTION
        return func(self.__class__.__base__, html)
```

Doing so, you should be able to have your child view documented by the parent docstring.